# Golang: Automatic Refresh of a HTTP Page

Tags: go

I have a HTTP page getting executed using Go programming language. The function in GO looks like this:

```
func main(){
    ...
    http.HandleFunc("/Page", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        t:=template.New("New template")
        child_template := t.New("New child template")
        _, _ = child_template.Parse(output)  // output is from the omitted code
        t, err = t.ParseFiles("HTML_template.html")
        _ = t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "HTML_template.html", output)
    }
}
```

How do I make /Page refreshes by itself? I have tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
func main(){
    ...
    http.HandleFunc("/Page", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        for{
            t:=template.New("New template")
            child_template := t.New("New child template")
            _, _ = child_template.Parse(output)  // output is from the omitted code
            t, err = t.ParseFiles("HTML_template.html")
            _ = t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "HTML_template.html", output)

            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond*100)
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a dynamic graph that plots the number of incoming data per second. If I keep making the browser refreshes, the axis will get reloaded too and it looks ugly. The HTML_template.html looks like this

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function plot(){
        ...
        var data = [{{template "New child template"}}];
        ...
    }
    setInterval(func(){plot()},500);
</script>
```

Comment: You must convince the browser to ask you the page again. This is usually done with JavaScript. But 100 ms is very short...

Comment: The browser reloads a page by requesting it again. The server doesn't have anything to do with that.

Comment: ok, making the browser to refresh makes sense. I am trying to make a dynamic graph that plots the number of incoming data per second. If I keep making the browser refreshes, the axis will get reloaded too and it looks ugly.

Comment: look into websockets or longpoll ajax.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done without Go, JavaScript, AJAX, SSE or Websockets by simply adding the [refresh](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp) meta tag. Adding

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" />
```

into your page's `<head>` will cause it to refresh every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You're going at this the wrong way, you should use Websockets [Gorilla](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/websocket)'s or [go.net](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket)'s or at the very least use ajax, but reloading the whole page is very inefficient.

Comment: It's a debugger for a server, so I don't really care about aesthetic or efficiency.

Answer (score -1):

Your really really really need to use websockets to do this but there is a quick and dirty method.

Add a little jquery to the page:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('reload')==-1) {
     window.location.replace(window.location.href+'?reload');
}
```

But you really need to use websockets.